# How do I delete an instance of a class in python (by force)?

Tags: python, mechanize, mechanize-python

I'm using a script to test if a website runs smoothly, basically I open the site every 20 minutes or so and check the response time and so on. Like this:

```
while True:

    MechBrowser = mechanize.Browser()
    Response = MechBrowser.open("http://example.com")
    time.sleep(1000)
```

I know python will do garbage collection itself and we should really not bother, but when I check network monitor I always find several unclosed connection each running 1h or more. And not all of the connection opened would hang there, just some of them. I'm confused, or maybe there's a method to destroy these instances manually?

Comment: It doesn't have a `.close()` method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try also closing your response object.

Answer (score 6):

`del`the object manually, notice that this will *not* delete the object but will just decrement the `reference count` of the object. When the `reference count`of an object reaches `zero` the garbage collector removes it from the memory.

Comment: You can also force the garbage collector to run using `gc.collect()` (`import gc` first), although this might not be necessary in CPython.

Comment: Will the instance clean up after itself if deleted?

Comment: Yes the instance will call its `__del__` method to clean up.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use multiprocessing to ensure all the used resources are closed after checking:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
import urllib2

def check_url(url):
    try:
        f = urllib2.urlopen(url) 
        f.close()
        print "%s working fine" % url
    except Exception as exc:
        print "Error ", exc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        p = Process(target=check_url, args=("http://www.google.com", ))
        p.start()
        p.join()
        time.sleep(5)
```